Sewing is making my clothes clip through my character
I want to make a default character with realistic clothes to my game. This is the first time I'm making them, so I can't figure out why are my clothes getting so tight, that it clips through my character.
I made multiple attempts with various tutorials on YouTube and answers to similar problems (on Stack Exchange and other) and every time the same thing prevents me from making it right.
Here are some screenshot from the last attempt:

back of the cloth

front of the cloth

3rd frame of sewing

20th frame of sewing


As you see the normals of both the cloth and the body are not correctly oriented, just flip them:


Thanks! I'll try to fix it tomorrow (I'm in europe).

Wow! Thanks! It works! I can't believe, I made such as mistake. Thanks again!
